# Definir márgenes UICollectionView Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Estoy haciendo una app que sea un lector de noticias.

Quiero que cuando sale la lista de noticias aparezca de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente lo muestro asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para la segunda columna quede centrada y no hacia la derecha? He probado con constraints pero no me afecta a las dos columnas, por lo que no queda bien.

El código que uso es este:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: OfertasCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OfertasCollectionViewCell

    cell.titulo.text = "TITULO"
    cell.desc.text = "DESCRIPCIÓN"
    cell.imagen.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")

    cell.vista.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)

    return cell
}
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con centrada?

Comment: Que quede como en wallapop, si te fijas, la columna de la derecha está hacia la derecha, en vez de estar mas centrada, o hacia la izquierda

Comment: ¿Querrás decir que una columna está más arriba que la otra no?

Comment: No, la columna de la derecha, no tiene margen derecho. Igual que en wallapop, que las columnas tienes margen izquierdo y derecho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes configurar ese margen en los `insets` del `UICollectionView`.

Concretamente `Section Insets Right`

[image: UICollectionView insets]